# Check radio button based on range slider value

Tags: jquery

I have a range slider with integer labels (1 through 5) and a radio checklist with the same labels. I want to check the radio button with corresponding value when the slider is change. For example, If the range slider is set to 3, the radio button labelled "3" is also checked. When the slider changes, so does the input.

The solution on the third example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HFYuZ/) is exactly what I want to do, but it's written for JQuery 1.7.2 and doesn't work in JQuery 3.4.1. I'm not well versed enough in Jquery to know the differences in syntax between versions. How do I update this code?

The Jquery from the linked solution is as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $(".slider").each(function () {
        var begin = $(this).data("begin"),
            end = $(this).data("end");

        $(this).slider({
            range: "min",
            min: begin,
            max: end,
            animate: true,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                //update text box quantity
                var slideramount = ("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_amount");
                $(slideramount).val(ui.value);
            }
        })

        //initialise text box quantity
        var slideramount = ("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_amount");
        $(slideramount).val($(this).slider("value"));
    })

    //When text box is changed, update slider
    $('.amount').change(function () {
        var value = this.value,
            selector = $("#" + this.id.split('_')[0]);
        selector.slider("value", value);
    })

    //When radio buttons are changed, update slider 
    $('[name="[smoker]"]').change(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $('#smoker').slider("value", value);
    });

    //When slider is changed, update radio buttons 
    $('#smoker').on('slidechange', function () {
        $('[name="[smoker]"][value="' + $(this).slider('value') + '"]').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think the jquery version is the problem but `slider()` is part of jquery.ui. So just add it after your jquery script.

**For example:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```